# Tag synonym request: mini-game / mini-games

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

I don't have the necessary reputation to formally propose tag synonyms, but I think the [mini-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-game) and [mini-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-games) tags should be merged and/or made synonyms. I'm not entirely sure how it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done in the direction of [mini-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-game) → [mini-games](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mini-games).

```
updating post history, 14 rows affected
updating posts, 8 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 8 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 1 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [mini-games] and [mini-game] complete!
```